# WPF :-Assembly reference issue(Are you missing an assembly reference)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, prism, wpf-4.0

I have one WPF project which is referring to another WPF project within the same solution.When I include namespace in first project in xaml file or its .cs file while compile time it shows the error like"Are you missing an assembly reference of project 2" .

Comment: Open the output window during the build, what is the first error you see ?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'XYZ' does not exist in the namespace 'ABC' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Compile project A, Project B has a reference to project A right ? after project A is compiled successfully, Compile project B.

Answer (score 0):

You Just Need to Set your Build Order Properly.

Your Ideal Build Order should be like this

1) Independent Project(project 2 in your case)
2) Dependent Project(project 1 in your case)

Second thing, to consider is that there is no cyclic reference.